# How can I get current system time with microsecond precision in eCos OS?

Tags: c, operating-system, real-time, embedded-linux, ecos

I know the default eCos precision is `1 ticks = 10 ms`.

And eCos OS provide `cyg_current_time();`

I can use cyg_current_time divide the tick_per_one_ms to get SystemTime_MS;

(e.g.) `GetSystemTime = cyg_current_time() / 10;`

How can I get System time with us precision ?

I want to calculate one time interval for us precision.

### For example(Want to know how much time that A() cost):

```
startTime = GetSystemTimeUS();
A();
endTime = GetSystemTimeUS();

printf("A() cost %lu us.",endTime - startTime);
```

---

I have tried many method, but it didn't work.

1. gettimeofday: it seams that eCos implement, but it still ms precision.
2. get tick: but 1 tick is 10ms. it means that context switching time is ms precision.
3. timer, clock , etc....

What I mean is that I want to implement a get Current System time function with us precision.

Comment: Can you skip eCos and use a timer directly in your hardware?

Comment: I am afraid that I can't not do this. I tried timer directly and the result  is ok. But the timer need to preserve for other task. So, I can not use it.

Comment: If you want do a performance measurement of A(), and A() needs about the same time every call, you could call A() 1000 times and measure the complete time. But i see that this solution only works for specific cases.

Comment: 2 Questions: Did you try clock_gettime() with different clk_ids? And is it possible that your hardware timers not have a better precision and so the functions can not get better results? (you can get the precision with clock_getres(), and as far as i know, you can not get better values from the kernel)

Comment: How can I use clock_gettime() to implement getSystemTime_US? I do not know the convert formula of [clock - time]

Comment: what you do not understand from the man page? It fills a structure with the time in nanoseconds, you must just divide this value by 1000, and add the seconds*1000000 to a uin64_t. Maybe you want to write the values of clock_getres() to see if the precision is accurate enough.

Comment: thanks for comment, What do you mean that "write the values of clock_getres() to see if the precision is accurate enough"? I trace the clock_getres(), it use tick for 1 unit. So, it has nanosecond attribute , but it stiil not work. Because 1 tick for 10 ms. Right? Or would you please give me a sample code to show how to implement the getSystemTimeUS() by using clock_gettime()?

Comment: I comment the clock_* functions because there is a tag embedded-linux. This functions are specific to posix-systems, and as far i read eCos is not Linux based and also not posix compatible. is that true (i did not know eCos)? in this case you can not use this functions anyway. Maybe you must use some hardware timers for that (and write a handler that you can use the same hardware timer for different things)